# Android - How to get my 3rd party library to access a generic view hierarchy

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

I'm building an Android library that is suppose to iterate through the app, and print it's view hierarchy.

Obviously, I'm trying to build it as seamlessly as possible to the developer.

My strategy for iOS is to ask the developer to 'init' my SDK upon launch, and run a background thread that polls the root window and looks for UI elements on the controller.

In Android, I want to keep the same strategy, but found it hard to get access to the root Activity, since Android doesn't allow this type of action.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From an `Activity`, you can call `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()` to access the root view.

The following code traverses the view tree hierarchy and displays the class names and ids of all the views.

```
   private void traverseViews( Activity activity ) {
      traverseViews( activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), 0 );
   }

   private void traverseViews( View view, int indentLevel ) {
      Log.e( "traverse",
         String.format( "%sView: class: %s id: %d",
            repeat( " ", indentLevel ),
            view.getClass().getName(),
            view.getId() ) );

      if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
         ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
         for ( int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            traverseViews( viewGroup.getChildAt( i ), indentLevel + 1 );
         }
      }
   }

   private String repeat( String string, int n ) {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
         builder.append( string );
      }
      return builder.toString();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way I can get the top Activity without explicitly asking it from the developer?

Comment: You could write a `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` that could be registered via `Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. It would get notified whenever an Activity is created, started, resumed, etc.